# Attempting a PUT to Google Groups API using OAuth2 gem and Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, faraday, faraday-oauth

I'm trying to do a PUT call on a Google Groups API using Ruby and the OAuth2 GEM.  I've managed to authenticate OK, and the GET call works properly, but I can't seem to get the call to use the PUT method.   I thought the following would work, since OAuth2 uses Faraday, but I just keep getting the 400 message back, with an indication that something's "required":

```
data = access_token.put('https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/{email address}?alt=json').parsed do |request|
  request.params['email'] = "{email address}"
end
```

Has anyone got a working example of passing parameters to a PUT request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  Looks like the ".parsed" was interfering with the call here's what works, with some additions to the request object:

```
response = access_token.put('https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/{email address}') do |request|
  request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  request.body='{"email": "{email address}"}'
end
# check this
puts response.status
# works if it's 200
```